# Explanation of Big Endian and Little Endian (Visual Studio C++, .asm)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, endianness

I've been looking at Big Endian and Little Endian and understand that they are the samething, but in different order. Such as Big has the larger numbers first and Little has the smaller numbers going first. This is an easy concept to understand. Why we would write it in code makes sense as well (some machines read Big others read small).

Our teacher wants us to write the code Big Endian to Little Endian and that is where my difficulty comes in. I am currently taking Java as well so when I write machine code for example:

```
.data
bigEndian BYTE 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h
```

I want to assign it a value, but I do not think that is my problem. My problem is understanding this in code. I look at this and bigEndian already looks like it is in LittleEndian form (12 smallest, 78 largest). Can someone explain or direct me to a location to understand the coding process of this? Thank you.

We are using C++ for Visual Studio and also using a .asm program.

Comment: Endianess plays a role when the processor reads or writes a value that requires *more* than one byte of storage.  An *int* for example, 4 bytes on most machines.  So don't use BYTE, bytes don't have an endianess problem, use (say) DWORD.